# CDetailView Error: The asset to be published does not exist

Tags: php, yii

I have a view that calls the Yii Framework CDetailView as follows:

```
<?php
$model = new partialUser();
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView',array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
            'user_id',
            'gender',
            'is_smoker',
            ),
)
); 
?>
```

The error I recieve is:

```
The asset "C:\wamp\www\wmpn\framework\zii\widgets\assets" to be published does not exist.
```

The partialUser model being called by the view is fairly straightforward:

```
public function attributeLabels(){
    return array(
            'user_id'=>'User',
            'gender'=>'Gender',
            'is_smoker'=>'Smoker?',             
            );
}
```

Are there any other attributes I need to include to ensure that CDetailView renders correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is related to the Javascript/image assets for CDetailView not being properly published to your assets folder.  It looks like the framework/zii/widgets/assets folder isn't there (or is corrupt / unreadable in some way).

Your partialView stuff looks fine, so I don't think that's your problem (or at least, I don't think that it's causing this error :-)